# Handle instances of classes created by services in a bundle?

Tags: java, osgi

How can one handle instances of classes created by services in a bundle? This causes problems when there instances are kept by the host application (application with embedded osgi container) and the bundle updates. After the update there are 2 versions of class instances around. Not ideal.

I found a couple solutions:

- let the bundle be responsible for class instances
- let the host application serialize/deserialize instance on update
- use reflection to access instances
- use a not changeable data object (for example a hashmap) for all services

Comment: What do you mean by host application? Is it also a bundle that uses OSGi services of another bundle? Or the host application has an embedded OSGi container?

Comment: @BalazsZsoldos The host application is indeed a embedded osgi container. Although it might be converted to a bundle in the far future, but that is still a change too far.

Answer (score 0):

In your case (embedded OSGi container), typically the host application contains the interfaces that the OSGi services implement.

Based on your last three options, I guess you do not want to re-generate the instances with the new OSGi service. If the API is in the host application, you do not have to do anything. The type of the instances are from bundles that are deleted, that does not matter. Only the API matters. As your instances are Serializable, I guess they do not have to be closed (to close some stream or whatever).

If you want to re-generate the instances each time the OSGi service is available again, you can implement a ServiceTracker in the Host Application and catch the events of registering and de-registering the OSGi services.

If your Host Application were a bundle, you could have used Declarative Services to implement your logic, so that you could avoid the usage of low-level APIs like ServiceTracker.

Comment: The instances the services create extend the api, api functions function normally after bundle update, the problem lies at the additions to these instances, for example an extra field. To access this field a service need to cast it to a non api interface and this goes wrong after an bundle update (which makes sense). My 4 solutions solve this problem to variable extend, but i was looking for better ways to handle such cases. Cheers!

Comment: Hmm, i can also add the extended api of the bundle to the systempackages of the host application, then everything works. But that would mean that if the extended api changes i have to restart the host application, nor can i plugin new bundles.

Comment: Yes if the API changes you have to restart the host application. But of course you can still add/remove/update bundles within the OSGi Framework... why do you think this is not possible?